# Numpy array rounding

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Recently I've been following some methods from a prior question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37780057/explanation-on-numpy-broadcasting-answer).

I've created a script to use it, and added some visualization to help show the issue I am having.

```
#Python 2.7, import future division
from __future__ import division
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

#Set length of sides and number of divisions of each side
latva = 6
latvb = 6
latvc = 6
latdiv = 20

#Step of each iteration per side
latvadiv = latva / latdiv
latvbdiv = latvb / latdiv     
latvcdiv = latvc / latdiv

#Init array of zeroes
lol = np.zeros((latdiv**3,4),dtype=np.float64)

#Change zero array to number array, 
lol[:,:3] = np.arange(latdiv**3)[:,None]//(latdiv**2,latdiv,1)*(latvadiv,latvbdiv,latvcdiv)%(latva,latvb,latvc)

#Mark lattice sides
for item in lol:

    if (item[0] < latvadiv/2 ) and (item[1] < latvbdiv/2):
        item[3] = 99       
    elif (item[0] < latvadiv/2) and (item[2] < latvcdiv/2):
        item[3] = 99
    elif (item[1] < latvbdiv/2) and (item[2] < latvcdiv/2):
        item[3] = 99

#Remove anything that is not a lattice side
lol = lol[~(lol[:,3] < 99)]

#Graph display
x = lol[:,[0]]
y = lol[:,[1]]
z = lol[:,[2]]
v = lol[:,[3]]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(x, y, z, zdir='z', s=20, c=v, depthshade=True)
plt.show()
```

Now if this is run, you get a pretty little 3d graph that show exactly what it is supposed to: 3 lines with 20 points each.

Now, change

```
latva = 6
latvb = 6
latvc = 6
```

to

```
latva = 3.007164
latvb = 3.007164
latvc = 3.007164
```

and watch how the graph gets destroyed, when in theory (In my understanding -  which very well may be wrong) the points on the graph should just be spaced closer together. 20 points within 3.007164 units instead of 20 points within 6 units.

Now in the "Change zero array to number array " section if you replace the very last part, the mod part, with:

```
(round(latva,5),round(latvb,5),round(latvc,5))
```

you get a correct graph again. Then if you change it to round to the 4th place instead of the 5th, you get a messed up graph again which leads me to believe this entire issue stems from rounding issues during the mod broadcast operation. Does anyone have any idea what exactly the issue is, and how to avoid it?

Comment: What is your main goal? Plotting 3 perpendicular lines with adjustable spacing, or understanding numpy's broadcasting system and indexing hacks?

Comment: @Finwood In this case understanding how the broadcasting is working to disrupt the array like that. The graph is purely for a visualization aid, as manually looking through a 8000 line array is a little tedious.

Answer (score 0):

It does seem to be an issue with the mod operation.

I solved it by adding:

```
    latva = round(latva,3)
    latva = list(str(latva))
    if (int(latva[-1]) - 1) != -1:
        latva[-1] = str(int(latva[-1]) - 1)
    latva = float("".join(latva))

    latvb = round(latvb,3)
    latvb = list(str(latvb))
    if (int(latvb[-1]) - 1) != -1:
        latvb[-1] = str(int(latvb[-1]) - 1)
    latvb = float("".join(latvb))

    latvc = round(latvc,3)
    latvc = list(str(latvc))
    if (int(latvc[-1]) - 1) != -1:
        latvc[-1] = str(int(latvc[-1]) - 1)
    latvc = float("".join(latvc))
```

just before the non-zero array creation.