# Create Numpy Array Representing a Geometric Shape

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, geometry

As the title suggests, how would one create a numpy array of 3D coordinates of a geometric shape?

Currently, I have the easiest shape already figured out:

```
latva = 6
latvb = 6
latvc = 6
latdiv = 20
latvadiv = latva / latdiv
latvbdiv = latvb / latdiv
latvcdiv = latvc / latdiv
lol = np.zeros((latdiv**3,4),dtype=np.float64)
lol[:,:3] = (np.arange(latdiv**3)[:,None]//(latdiv**2,latdiv,1)*(latvadiv,latvbdiv,latvcdiv)%(latva,latvb,latvc))
```

creates an array of (8000,4). If you then split the array along the 1,2,3 column (Ignoring the 4th as it's meaningless in this question) and plot it (Personally, I use pyplot) you get a Cube!

Easy enough. Also works for a rectangle.

But I've not the foggiest idea of how to get any further - say plotting a rhombus.

I'm not interested in black magic like spheres, ovals or shapes whose sides do not change following a line. Just things like your standard rhombus/Rhomboid/Parallelepiped/Whatever_you_want_to_call_it.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: What is pythonic abracadabra in the last line intended for? Fills array with 3D coordinates of regular grid points inside a cube? At the cube surface? At the edges?

Comment: @MBo It is explained here. http://stackoverflow.com/a/37780768/4999890 Sorry I cant make a clickable link on mobile.

Comment: three variables aren't defined somewhere latvadiv, latvbdiv, latvcdiv

Comment: @DanPatterson oops you are right, updated.

Answer (score 0):

Because you already have convenient method to generate points in square or cube, the simplest way to make rhombus, parallelogram for 2D case and parallelepiped for 3D case is to apply affine transform to calculate new point coordinates.

For example, to make rhombus, you can find matrix as combination of translation by (-centerX, -centerY), rotation by Pi/4, scaling along axes (if needed) and translation to needed position.

```
AffMatrix = ShiftMatrix * RotateMatrix * ScaleMatrix * BackShiftMatrix
for each point coordinates:
   (NewX, NewY) = (AffMatrix) * (X, Y)
```

Rhomboid will include also shear transform.

I think that `numpy` has ready-to-use routines to create and combine (multiply) affine matrices.